# Finding Cosine similarity threshold (cut-off point) with Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic, threshold, cosine-similarity

I want to preprocess my data sets, removing similar articles. To do this, I'll perform cosine similarity, I don't know the best threshold (cut-off point) of my data set. I Found in [this paper](https://www.mdpi.com/1999-5903/11/5/114/htm), there's no exact value of threshold because threshold values is depending of our data sets. So I found [this notebook code](https://anaconda.org/korawit/similarity_threshold/notebook) in that paper the way to get threshold. This examples use manually labeled 1000 pairs of similar and unsimilar data sets and making Logistic Regression model to find the cut-off cosine similarity(CSS) on 0.5 probability with variable:

x = cosine similarity values from pair of 2 sentences

y = "1" or "0" ("similar" or "unsimilar")

So, I try to perform it to my manually labeled data sets (I prepare just about 50 pairs similar and unsimilar manually labeled data) weighted by TF-IDF. Then I just wanna have fun to removing and adding my pairs data train sets.. but I got diverse threshold value. Then I tried to adding my labeled data to 250 pairs on each, but I found the threshold values is getting smaller, and I will losing a lot of data that are not actually similar, but are considered similar. Why I got the inconsistency threshold values?

Thank you for your kind help.